# Build kernel modules for specific Ubuntu version

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel

I am trying to build kernel module but when I try to load it I get

```
$ sudo insmod net/openvswitch/openvswitch.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module net/openvswitch/openvswitch.ko: Invalid module format
```

modinfo for module is:

```
name:           openvswitch 
vermagic:       6.5.13-g1daceaa37695 SMP preempt mod_unload
```

while kernel version is:

```
$ uname -a
Linux virtual-machine 6.5.0-25-generic #25~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Feb 20 16:09:15 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am using following repository:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/jammy (fetch)
origin  https://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/jammy (push)
```

And following tag/branch:

```
$ git branch 
* (HEAD detached at Ubuntu-hwe-6.5-6.5.0-25.25_22.04.1)
  master
```

The main problem seems is that I am unable to find the exact source code from where to build it.

Comment: You don't need any external repository to build kernel modules for your system. All you need is the package `linux-headers-$(uname -r)`. Install it and then you can point your module Makefile to `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build`. That's it.

Comment: I mean I want to add some code to existing code

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. That still does not change how you would build the module.

Comment: HAve you checked that signature is not used for the kernel you are trying to insert module into?